# TS2305: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'User'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, gitlab-ci, prisma

I am try to set up a Gitlab CI for a nestjs project that uses prisma. When I run the pipeline, I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skYpR.png)

My .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - corepack enable
    - corepack prepare pnpm@latest-8 --activate
    - pnpm config set store-dir .pnpm-store
  script:
    - pnpm install
    - npx prisma generate
    - pnpm run build
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - pnpm-lock.yaml
    paths:
      - .pnpm-store
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
```

`user.models.ts`:

```
import { User } from "@prisma/client"; # Line that is causing the build to fail in the CI
import { IsEmail, IsInt, IsNotEmpty, IsString } from "class-validator";

class UserModel implements User {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsInt()
    id: number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    @IsEmail()
    email: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    password: string;
}
```

Running `pnpm run build` locally works fine.

With the following scripts I have manually looked at the output generated by prisma, and I can see that `User` is being exported as a type from `index.d.ts`.

```
- cd ./node_modules/.prisma/client
- cat index.d.ts
- cd ../../..
```

Comment: Update: I realized that prisma generate is automatically run when doing `pnpm install` so I removed the `npx prisma generate` script and am still receiving the same error.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I needed to use `import type { User }` instead of `import { User }`.

Comment: your answer is not clear

Answer (score 3):

For anybody else with this issue, make sure you have set output value as it is below in your prisma.schema file for types to be stored, this ideally will be your node_modules directory

```
generator client {
  ...
  output = "../../node_modules/.prisma/client"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint! I was checking to see if the `.prisma/client` directory existed. It turned out that it didn't, so I ran `prisma generate`. This generated the necessary folder and resolved the `@prisma/client` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my schema.prisma to have this line of code
output = "../../node_modules/.prisma/client"
and then run npx prisma migrate dev
after running the above command it worked just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error in deployment, but in my case I'm building from a Dockerfile. So for anyone coming across the same but have a different setup, the fix was to add a line high up in the Dockerfile.

`COPY prisma ./`

Example

```
FROM node as installer
WORKDIR /app
COPY prisma ./
...the rest of your code
```